# Creating clickable dynamic links with typeahead.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, search, typeahead.js

I'd like to make it so the suggested results in my search's autocomplete link to the specific restaurant on the site.

**Note:** I came across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23510474/3046413) but it uses a static array of objects. Unlike this post I'm looking to generate links from the **server-side**.

```
var links = [{name: "abc", link: "http://www.example1.com"}, 
             {name: "nbc", link: "http://www.example2.com"}];

var source = new Bloodhound({
  ...
  local: links
});
```

In my case I'm querying from Rails a database so the `name` would be the restaurant's name and the `link` would be the `restaurant_path`. Based on what my current code, how I can I accomplish this? Let me know if any additional code is needed.

```
$(function() {
  var restaurants = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    remote: { 
      url: "/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY",
      wildcard: "%QUERY"
    }
  });

  restaurants.initialize();

  $('#autocomplete').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: restaurants.ttAdapter()
  });
});
```

The way my restaurant path currently looks is as follows:

```
localhost:3000/restaurants/blue-smoke
```

**Update:**

Following guest271314 suggestion I was able to find the return value for my restaurant objects, which includes the appropriate slugs (i.e. `blue-smoke`) to link up the suggested results.

Comment: I don't think you should be using bloodhound with server-based search. Anyway, just ignore the file part of the example and make your server return similar data, example will work!

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Not a duplicate being that question deals with static links. I'm dealing with server-side links.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Try returning suggestions within array returned by `remote` at `restaurants` , using `templates` property at second typeahead initialization object

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Little confused. If were to not use Bloodhound what else would I be using. As far as, "ignoring the file part", what are you referring to? Would you be able to provide an answer to further elaborate?

Comment: Ok, let's go back to the beginning. What happens when I post to this url? `/search/autocomplete?query=%QUERY`. Bloodhound IS a search engine so you could just feed it all the data and it will perform the search for you, without ever requesting the server. If your server filters the queries first then you duplicate this responsibility both on fronted and backend. However you can just ignore this and continue doing, it's just inefficient.

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand. With that said how would I go about in setting up the `links` variable?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Can you show how you are querying the database?  Are you rendering a json file in your controller?  When I define the datumTokenizer the same as you the typeahead dropdown shows all attributes of the matching active record object and not just the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `templates`, `suggesstion` option of second `.typeahead()` initialization object . See [Typeahead examples - Custom Templates](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#custom-templates)

```
$('#autocomplete').typeahead(null, {
    displayKey: 'name',
    source: restaurants.ttAdapter(),
    templates:{
      suggestion:function(data) {
        return "<a href=" + data.slug + ">"+ data.name +"</a>"
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: For some reason, `data` is returning `undefined`.

Comment: What is returned response from server ? , may require adding `filter` option at `Bloodhound` `remote`

Comment: I think I'm getting undefined because there's no `link` defined in the JSON object. I do though have a `slug` property with the appropriate name of the page. So instead of `data.link` it should be `data.slug`.

Comment: I guess you can say the only caveat is that I have to hardcode the sub-directory `restaurants` because of how my routing is setup. So the return value would be: `return "<a href=restaurants/" + data.link + ">"+ data.name +"</a>"`. Would you recommend a better way to do this or leave it as is?

Comment: @CarlEdwards Addings string "restaurants" before suggestion appear to be  simplest solution. See updated post

Comment: With your most recent answer I now get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'link' of undefined`. Why the change?

Comment: What is result of `console.log(data)` within `suggestion` ?

Comment: It returns `undefined`.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Try same at `filter` ; `console.log(response)` , `console.log(results)`

Comment: It doesn't seem to be picking up those logs. Only shows that undefined error.

Comment: Checked network tab ? Is response returned from server ?

Comment: Got everything working without hardcoding the sub-directory. It must've been a caching issue. If you'd like, you can revert your answer to the original one and I'd be more than happy to mark this as correct.

Comment: Oh one more thing. Could you just change `data.link` to `data.slug` in your answer. That seemed to be the missing link.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @guest271314 Where is the data coming from in the function for suggestion?

Comment: @user4584963 Array returned by `Bloodhound`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253261/create-customize-type-head-using-jquery-and-bootstrap-typeahead

Comment: @guest271314 When I define my datumTokenizer as Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name') I am getting typeahead filled with all attributes of my activerecord object and not just the name.  If I post a question would you mind taking a look?

Comment: @user4584963 _"If I post a question would you mind taking a look?"_ Sure

Comment: @guest271314 here's a link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34771714/typeahead-populating-with-all-attributes-of-active-record-object