# How to create an auto complete form based on a json file with links?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I want to create a form, that when the user clicks, it loads an external file with the items available for the search in the background. This form should also show suggestions based on the items names of the list only. Each option when selected goes to a link.

I've tried some stuff with jQuery, but I didn't find how to use the auto complete form with links, or to make it loads only after the click in the form (I have 3K options for this menu, and I can't load the list with the site load).

How can I achieve it?

Comment: You may want to add to the question, the code you've tried already. It tells us that you've at least made some effort...

Comment: This is completelly multi(any)level: https://jsfiddle.net/00kdjLz5/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674324/creating-clickable-dynamic-links-with-typeahead-js